# Characteristic polynomial as a norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, free-modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $B$ an $R$-algebra that is free as an $R$-module of finite rank $N$. For any element $f\in B$, we may consider the $R$-linear endomorphism of $B$ defined by multiplication by $f$. We then define the *characteristic polynomial* of $f$, denoted $\chi _f(T)$, by $$\chi _{B/R}^f(T)=\det(T-f)\in R[T].$$
In particular, we define the *norm* of $f$ as $$\operatorname{N}_{B/R}(f)=(-1)^N\chi _{B/R}^f(0)\in R.$$

Now, under the same context, we may consider the $R[T]$-algebra $B[T]$, which is free of finite rank $N$ as an $R[T]$-module. My question is the following:

Is the following identity in $R[T]$ true?

> $$N_{B[T]/R[T]}(T-f)=\chi _{B/R}^f(T)$$

In other words, is the characteristic polynomial of $f\in B$ the norm of $T-f$ relative to $B[T]/R[T]$?

If it is true, could someone please sketch a proof for it or give me a reference?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It looks right to me. $f$ multiplication is different from $T$ multiplication. $T$ multiplication as $R[T]$ module morphism does not change the basis but scale basis by $T$. So you can assemble the matrix representation by piece first. $T\cdot=diag\{T,\dots, T\}_n$. For $f$ multiplication, it mixes basis. Originally $B=<e_i>_R$. Now $B[T]=<e_i>_{R[T]}$ by tensoring. In particular, $f\cdot$ part mixes $e_i\otimes_R 1$ basis elements. This indicates that $f\cdot$ is represented as the same matrix before. Now assemble $T-f$ to see you get $T-f$ matrix in $B$ multiplication.

Comment: That give you the norm wrote there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I lost myself trying to compute things without thinking and I just got confused. However, your reasoning steps, analyzing bit by bit how the whole mechanics works, are very clear and make the solution appear naturally. I can understand it well now.